# Is there a block explorer for Ardor Testnet?

Tags: ardor, ignis

I'm looking for a block explorer for Ardor Testnet, but can't find one. I know of http://ardor.tools but that is only for main net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ardor portal block explorer also monitors the testnet, see https://test.ardorportal.org/monitor